# How can I conditionally change the color of text in a PlutoGrid Cell based on its value?

Tags: flutter

Just wondering if anyone knows how to conditionally change the color of the text in a PlutoGrid Cell based on value.

I am using pluto_grid:  ^7.0.2 in Flutter

I have obviously tried:

```dart
PlutoColumn(
          title: '% Change',
          field: 'percentChange',
          type: PlutoColumnType.number(),
          readOnly: true,
          titleTextAlign: PlutoColumnTextAlign.right,
          textAlign: PlutoColumnTextAlign.right,
          renderer: (rendererContext) {
           Color textColor =
                rendererContext.cell.value < 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.green;
            return Text(
              textAlign: TextAlign.right,
              rendererContext.cell.value.toString(),
              style: const TextStyle(
                debugLabel: 'blackCupertino bodySmall', 
                fontFamily: '.SF UI Text', 
                color: *textColor,*
                decoration: TextDecoration.none),
            );
          }),
```

However, PlutoGrid complains that the textColor is not a constant. I cannot declare textColor as constant since it is using a variable (Flutter will complain).. a catch 22

Comment: Could you put the `PlutoColumn` code in a code block so that it is easier to read for people trying to answer your question? You can use the `{}` "curly brackets" in the editor of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the `const` keyword in `const TextStyle( debugLabel: 'blackCupertino bodySmall', fontFamily: '.SF UI Text', color: textColor, decoration: TextDecoration.none),`

Removing the `const` keyword should therefore do the trick because you cannot use a `const` variable in front of a dynamic value.